# Shotgun not using appropriate ruby version (macosx)

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rbenv, shotgun

I am a bit new to this, so sorry if there are some missing infos initially.

I installed ruby 1.8.7 via homebrew initially, so I did with shotgun as well.

Then I realized that for a proper ruby+sinatra+shotgun combo, I'll need ruby 1.9.3, so I installed rbenv, and then installed ruby 1.9.3-p0 with it. After that, the ruby -v displays the correct new version, rbenv only lists 1.9.3 and marks it as installed, but when launching shotgun, the info says it is still using 1.8.7. The OS is Lion.

Here's the relevent output

```
Zsolts-iMac:test zsolt$ shotgun server.rb
== Shotgun/WEBrick on http://127.0.0.1:9393/
[2012-03-01 09:25:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-03-01 09:25:49] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
[2012-03-01 09:25:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=73577 port=9393

Zsolts-iMac:teste zsolt$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

Zsolts-iMac:teste zsolt$ rbenv versions
* 1.9.3-p0 (set by /Users/zsolt/Downloads/teste/.rbenv-version)

Zsolts-iMac:teste zsolt$ rbenv version
1.9.3-p0 (set by /Users/zsolt/Downloads/teste/.rbenv-version)
```

Comment: You should either close out your own question or answer it yourself in such a way that others will benefit and mark it as answered.

Comment: I recommend you to use rvm for multiple version of rubies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

shotgun was missing from the gem list, so I installed it (so possibly the issue was that I installed it via homebrew initially?), and ran a gem update, reloaded the terminal, and now shotgun is using 1.9.3 properly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't installed `shotgun` with Ruby 1.8.7. If that's the case, the `shotgun` binary will be available system-wide and when you'll fire it, it will load the Ruby 1.8.7 version.

Uninstall `shotgun` and install it using Ruby 1.9.3.